# Python strip or remove part of path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to remove part of a file path and leave only the file name as seen below

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/memento/files/329403216/2021-08-31 10.35.47.jpg, file:///storage/emulated/0/memento/files/329403216/2021-08-31 10.36.13.jpg, file:///storage/emulated/0/memento/files/329403216/2021-08-31 10.36.23.jpg
```

I would like the end result to be as follows

```
2021-08-31 10.35.47.jpg, 2021-08-31 10.36.13.jpg, 2021-08-31 10.36.23.jpg
```

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your input data is just several strings. You can convert them to [Path objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which offer rich interactions:

```py
from pathlib import Path

paths = [
    'file:///storage/emulated/0/memento/files/329403216/2021-08-31 10.35.47.jpg',
    'file:///storage/emulated/0/memento/files/329403216/2021-08-31 10.36.13.jpg',
    'file:///storage/emulated/0/memento/files/329403216/2021-08-31 10.36.23.jpg'
]
filenames = [Path(p).name for p in paths]
```

gives

```
['2021-08-31 10.35.47.jpg', '2021-08-31 10.36.13.jpg', '2021-08-31 10.36.23.jpg']
```

Comment: Jan, thanks. I will give this a test later today. My long term goal is to have this code use input from an excel spreadsheet and then remove the file path from each cell / row of data. Once that is completed then I will use a different column with a  inventory number to rename images using their current name. So in the end each image from that cell will be renamed inv#-1.jpg, inv#-2.jpg, inv#-3.jpg. Thanks for your input.